# What are the drawbacks of changing an internal python method?

Tags: python

I believe I've gotten into a bad habit recently when working with python. Sometimes, an internal method doesn't have all of the features I want, so I redefine the method locally. For example, I wanted to use the filter() method to search for methods in a module.

```
items=(x if 'query' in x.lower() else False for x in dir(module))
```

which returns a huge list. I wanted to filter this down with filter(), but the method seemed weirdly limited. The initial solution was:

```
items_filtered=filter(lambda x: x,items)
print([x for x in items_filtered.__iter__()])
```

Which seems like more lines than I want. Also I didn't like that **iter**() wipes the array clean, which is frustrating for notebook environments like Jupiter. I redefined the filter method as:

```
_filter = filter
class filter(_filter):
  def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    _filter.__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    itr = self.__iter__
    self.values = [x for x in self.__iter__()]
    self.__itr__ = itr
```

which allows the one liner to be

```
items=filter(lambda x,(x if 'query' in x.lower() else False for x in dir(module))).values
```

This is obviously not the 'right' way to handle these situations, but will it break anything when used in the wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you just want a list of all method names (of a given module) whose identifiers contain a specific substring. Why not simply:

```
print([x for x in dir(module) if "query" in x.lower()])
```

As far as the filter object goes, a filter is an iterator - it is evaluated lazily, and its contents are consumed as they are yielded/iterated over.
Instead of binding a filter object to a variable, just create an anonymous filter object on the line in which you intend to use it:

```
print([x for x in filter(...)])
```

or even better:

```
print(list(filter(...)))
```

Please don't explicitly use `__iter__()` to iterate over an iterator...